# Meaning of 'obligatory disclaimer'

Tags: probability

Can you explain to me what 'obligatory disclaimer' means in probability. Is it like a lack of information or what?

The context is the following:

Second, we found that the marginal distribution of Y is Bern(0.08), whereas the
conditional distribution of Y given X = 1 is Bern(0.2) and the conditional distribution
of Y given X = 0 is Bern(0.04). Since conditioning on the value of X alters
the distribution of Y , X and Y are not independent: learning whether or not the
sampled individual is a current smoker gives us information about the probability
that he will develop lung cancer.
This example comes with an ***obligatory disclaimer***. Although we have found that X
and Y are dependent, we cannot make conclusions about whether smoking causes
lung cancer based on this association alone. (Joseph K. Blitzstein, Jessica Hwang--Introduction to Probability)

Comment: It's not a probability term. It means they feel they have a duty (an obligation) to include the sentence that follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with probability theory and vocabulary in itself, but rather the two words [obligatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obligatory) and [disclaimer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclaimer) in regular English. Basically, they're saying that any time you point out a correlation, you should warn that this does not mean causation.

Comment: Also, [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/552/) (meaning that any time there is a relevant XKCD to post, you should post it).